# Map super/windows key to KDE Menu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 16.10, kde5

I want to use the Super/Windows key to open the KDE Menu at the bottom left. I really do not want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as I am switching from Windows to Kubuntu and I want to retain this functionality. Also, I cannot use ksuperkey as that does not support 16.10 (the version that I use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you describe has been implemented in KDE Plasma 5.8, and is available "out-of-the-box" in that version. Unfortunately, Kubuntu 16.10 contains Plasma 5.7, so it does not have that feature. You will most likely have to wait until Kubuntu 17.04 to get that feature in the official Ubuntu packages.

If you are more adventurous, you can try the Kubuntu Backports PPA, which very recently (6 days ago at the time of writing) added KDE Plasma 5.8.4 packages. However, if you are just beginning under Linux, this may be a lot of things to learn at once, and there is a risk you screw up your install. Here is the announce (with minimal instructions) about that: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-and-linux-mint-doing-plasma-5-8-testing/

Comment: Yea, I'm quite new to Linux so I'm not going to try that :)